# After app installation I can't open it

Tags: android, launch

I have created an simple app with a few activities. After successful installation I can't open the app. I can just see it in device's apps.

Yes of course a read all the answers telling "You have to set launcher activity". But I set launcher activity.

Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cz.jacon.davodani"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.1">

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">

</application>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
    android:label="@string/search_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.CustomerActivity"
    android:label="@string/customer_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.CreditActivity"
    android:label="@string/credit_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.PrintReceiptActivity"
    android:label="@string/print_receipt_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ProductActivity"
    android:label="@string/product_activity">
</activity>
```

Never before happened to me... Can you give me some advice? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your activities are required to be defined within the `<application>` tag.

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">

   <!-- Add activites here -->

</application>
```

Comment: Oh no! This is such a beginner's mistake... I will rather learn to knit... Thank you so much, you save my time.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cz.jacon.davodani"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.1">

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cz.jacon.davodani"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.1">

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">

<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
    android:label="@string/search_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.CustomerActivity"
    android:label="@string/customer_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.CreditActivity"
    android:label="@string/credit_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.PrintReceiptActivity"
    android:label="@string/print_receipt_activity">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ProductActivity"
    android:label="@string/product_activity">
</activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

try Replacing your manifest with this..

Answer (score 0):

Change your AndroidManifest.xml structure to -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cz.jacon.davodani"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.1">

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/search_activity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CustomerActivity"
        android:label="@string/customer_activity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CreditActivity"
        android:label="@string/credit_activity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.PrintReceiptActivity"
        android:label="@string/print_receipt_activity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProductActivity"
        android:label="@string/product_activity">
    </activity>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

All activities tag must be placed inside `<application>` tag and it should be placed inside `<manifest>` tag.